# sum of counts within same row Power apps

Tags: powerapp

need to the display the total counts of three different columns that display "FREE" within the same gallery row.
using formula:

CountIf('Desk reservation',Status = "FREE", Status_2= "FREE", Status_3= "FREE")

Formula above is only giving the total amount of rows and only for one column.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below formula to calculate the values based on different columns in a single row,

```
With({
    status1: If(ThisItem.Status = "Free", 1, 0),
    status2: If(ThisItem.Status_2 = "Free", 1, 0),
    status3: If(ThisItem.Status_3 = "Free", 1, 0)
}, Sum(status1, status2, status3))
```

Hope this solves your problem in PowerApps.

Comment: Dear Shantha, it worked nicely. Excellent out of the box thinking! Thanks a million

Comment: I needed to add to the add if result =0, red colour otherwise green. 
On the fill function I'm using, it is not changing red in 0 .
any ideas?

If(With({
    status1: If(ThisItem.Status = "Free", 1, 0),
    status2: If(ThisItem.Status_2 = "Free", 1, 0),
    status3: If(ThisItem.Status_3 = "Free", 1, 0)
}, Sum(status1, status2, status3))= "0",   RGBA(220,50,35,1), RGBA(25,170,110, 1))

Comment: Remove the double quotes around 0.  Use the below formula,   If(With({ 
status1: If(ThisItem.Status = "Free", 1, 0), 
status2: If(ThisItem.Status_2 = "Free", 1, 0), 
status3: If(ThisItem.Status_3 = "Free", 1, 0) 
}, Sum(status1, status2, status3))= 0, RGBA(220,50,35,1), RGBA(25,170,110, 1))

Comment: Shantha, thanks a million. it worked great! :)

Comment: you're welcome.